# .NET help for Data Validation in DocuSign

Tags: .net, docusignapi

I am trying to create a string to validate a text field in DocuSign. I want to make sure this field has exactly 9 numbers entered, otherwise I want it to trigger a validation error in DocuSign.

DocuSign gives an example of this validation language, saying that

> ^(?=[^\d_].*?\d)\w(\w|[!@#$%]){7,20}

will validate a field to make sure that it's "restricted to a length of 8 to 20 alphanumeric characters and select special characters. The password also cannot start with a digit, underscore, or special character, and must contain at least one digit." Since what I want to do is much simpler, I'm hoping to pick the basic validation language from this to do what I need. I don't have a high understanding of .NET code, but I can trial-and-error it.

I was wondering if anyone with more experience can help me with this process. So far, it looks like

> ^(?=[^\d_].*?\d)\w(\w|[!@#$%]){8,10}

would work for what I need, except that I want to remove the language that's stopping it from starting with a digit.  I am trying to figure out the code so I know which part causes this. If anyone can even link me to .NET resources to help me learn this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in your quote boxes is a Regex. If you only want 9 digits and absolutely nothing else:

```
var regex = @"^\d{9}$";

var valid = "888888888";
var invalid = "nine nines";

var validMatch = Regex.Match(valid, regex);
if (validMatch.Success) // This matches 
{

}

var invalidMatch = Regex.Match(invalid, regex);

if (invalidMatch.Success) //This will not.
{

}
```

You also didn't tag the .NET language you're using so I assumed C#.

For learning Regex, I used (and still use) a combination of [Rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/) for learning/looking up what I need and [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) for live-testing my Regexes.

I'm in no way affiliated with either of those sites.

Comment: Thank you so much, inputting

Comment: inputting
> \d{9}
worked. Altho it lets me use numbers with MORE than 9 digits, it blocks ones with less than 9. Which is fine for my purposes. You saved me a lot of trouble :)

Comment: It's doing that because the Regex engine will match the first 9 and then try to match again after that. You can check to see if there's only one match, or use the start-of-line and end-of-line syntax for the Regex: `^\d{9}$`